# django.core.validators is not a package

Tags: python, django, debian, importerror

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of days and still can't figure out why this is happening.
I'm trying to at least access a shell via manage.py or perform a migration.
(django 1.9.8, python 3.5.2)

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "gris/gris/manage.py", line 14, in <module>
      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/home/user/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
      utility.execute()
    File "/home/user/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
      self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/home/user/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
      klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
    File "/home/user/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 39, in load_command_class
      module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
    File "/home/user/Python-3.5.2/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ImportError: No module named 'django.core.validators.management'; 'django.core.validators' is not a package
```

I'm trying to run the script from inside the virtual environment. The weird part is: everything works on MacOS machines and PyCharm is able to run the server.

What have i tried so far:

1. Made sure i'm using the correct version of python and django.
2. Took manage.py from a freshly created project and replaced
3. Grep'ed the filesystem for 'django.core.validators'
4. Downloaded Python sources, compiled them locally and created new virtual environment
5. Tried running it without virtual environment
6. Tried different django(1.9.0, 1.9.6, 1.9.5) and python(3.4, 3.5.2) versions

I ran out of ideas what could cause that. Django.core.validators is not a package, it's a .py file and apparently there's no code trying to access in differently.

Any ideas/suggestions?

My project structure: [image: my_project_structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error would perhaps be raised if `django.core.validators` was in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

If it is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, then it shouldn't be there because it's not an app. Remove it.

Comment: Wow thank you! It really was there, but i don't remember putting it there though

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/) and indeed the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/core/validators/) `django.core.validators` is a module, and does not contain a `management` attribute.